# Trying to understand statics is java, Why is it that this is the output in this code?

Tags: java, static

```
class Cup {
  Cup(int marker) {
    System.out.println("Cup(" + marker + ")");
  }

  void f(int marker) {
    System.out.println("f(" + marker + ")");
  }
}

class Cups {
  static Cup c1;
  static Cup c2;
  static {  
    c1 = new Cup(1);
    c2 = new Cup(2);
  }
  Cups() {
    System.out.println("Cups()");
  }
}

public class ExplicitStatic {
  static Cups x = new Cups();
  static Cups y = new Cups();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Inside main()");
  }      
}
```

Output:

```
Cup(1)
Cup(2)
Cups()
Cups()
Inside main()
```

So there are two static Cups,
    in class ExplicitStatic, why its only showing 
    Cup(1) && Cup(2)?

Comment: Were you expecting `Cup(1) Cup(2)` to be printed twice then?

Comment: yes, like Cup(1)
Cup(2)
Cups()
Cup(1)
Cup(2)
Cups()
Inside main()

Comment: So *why* were you expecting that? You have two static `Cup` fields, each of which is initialized once. Does my answer make sense to you?

Comment: If I understand it, c1 & c2 had been initialized in one static block.. so this is shared every time a new Cups object is created? does this explains why there are only two instance of Cup?

Comment: It's not that it's shared, so much as that it isn't specific to any particular instance - if you just called a static method within `Cups`, *never* creating any instances of `Cups`, you'd still end up with those two instances of `Cup`. Static variables (and methods) are associated with the type, not with any particular instance of the type.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `static` variables will be initialized once.

Comment: but isnt static cups x and static cups y creates a different instance of Cup?

Comment: @JavaNoob Different Cups yes. But the static variables are the same for all instances.

Answer (score 1):

The only time that `new Cup()` is called is within the static initializer block for `Cups`.

That will only be executed once, however many instances of `Cups` you create - indeed, even if you don't create *any* instances of `Cups`, so long as you force the `Cups` class to be initialized (e.g. by calling a static method on it).

If you want two `Cup` instances *per instance of `Cups`* then you should use instance fields instead, e.g.

```
class Cups {
  Cup c1 = new Cup(1);
  Cup c2 = new Cup(2);

  Cups() {
    // This will execute *after* the field initializers above
    System.out.println("Cups()");
  }
}
```

Then you'd get output of:

```
Cup(1)
Cup(2)
Cups()
Cup(1)
Cup(2)
Cups()
Inside main()
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, so in my code which static has been called? is it x or y?  which one is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

java allows you to group other **static** initialization inside a special "**static clause**" (sometimes called a static block) in a class.

in your code

```
static {  
    c1 = new Cup(1);
    c2 = new Cup(2);
      }
```

will execute only once :
the first time you make an object of that class or the first time you access a **static** member of that class even if you never make an object of that class.